# Timing multiple blocks in qualtrics and sending to a new block at the end of the time

Tags: timer, block, qualtrics

I need to design a study on qualtrics. 
I am fairly new on qualtrics. 
I have 11 block of questions.

- Block 1 = consent.
- Block 2 = Additional Info.
- Block 3 to Block 7 = Independent variable related questions.
- Block 8 moderator related questions.
- Block 9 dependent variable related questions.
- Block 10 manipulation check related questions.
- Block 11 = thank you.

I need my timer to start at the beginning of block 3 and allow the participants 30 minutes to complete up to block 9. After 30 minutes, they need to see block 10. I tried talking to the qualtrics support and they told me to use `Q_TotalDuration` but I am not able to do so.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why can't you use `Q_TotalDuration`? Do you have code where you have attempted to do so (not required, but helpful)?

Comment: I tried using Q_TotalDuration at multiple places (end of each block). However, when I export the data, Time appears at two places only and both of the show the same time. I need time at the end of each block.